# Vue.js data inside erb link_to tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I'm working on a rails app and one page uses vue.js to load a google map, do few api calls with axios and capture some user values using vue.js. I want to submit these values as parameters within a "link_to" erb tag. See code snippet below

Below is my vue instance hardcoded data.

```
 let vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-map',
  data: {
    selectedProductId: 46,
    latt: '-26.29217',
    long: '28.070820000000026'
   }
```

Below is a snippet from the actual index.html.erb file.

```
<div class='panel-footer'>
    <%= link_to 'Continue',maps_path(:product => {{selectedProductId}}) ,class: "btn btn-success"%>
</div>
```

I get the following error " syntax error, unexpected '}' ".

I tried with and without quotes. Without quotes, I get the syntax error and with quotes, it does go through but in my rails controller the parameter is a string and not the value in vue data.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around my problem using "v-bind". I used a normal anchor tag instead of rails "link_to".

Below is a snippet of index.html.erb

```
  <div class='panel-footer'>
    <a v-bind:href="'/maps/customer_detail?product=' + selectedProductId" class='btn btn-success'>Continue</a>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps anyone using Vue.js inside rails html.erb files